# How to exclude Outlook 2010 from Win7 roaming profiles

Tags: group-policy, outlook-2010, roaming-profile

We have a user with sensitive emails that shouldn't be available when they login to a borrowed computer that is not their primary computer. We want to keep their Win7 roaming profile but exclude the Outlook profile leaving it up to the user to choose to configure Outlook on each computer they visit if they require it.

We have Win7, Outlook 2010, Microsoft Exchange, Active Directory and Group Policy.

How can this be achieved? Is there perhaps a Group Policy setting that can control this? From what I've read so far it appears the Outlook profile configuration is stored in the registry and not in the file system.

Comment: What active directory server(s) do you have?

Comment: You could script wiping HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\Outlook\Profiles at logoff and script importing that key only on the primary computer, I guess?

Comment: I would recommend OWA for this purpose. It's pretty good in 2013, and not that bad in 2010.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the data in the Outlook profile is excluded already. Roaming profiles excludes the appdata\local folder which is where most of the outlook data is stored.

If there are other locations you want to exclude, you can exclude directories/folders from roaming profiles through your group policy.

In your group policy object:

1. Browse to: User/Admin Templates/System/User Profiles
2. Edit "Exclude directories in roaming profiles" setting
3. Enable and add the appropriate directories you want to exclude

[image]

edit: 
Yes, there is outlook profile information stored in the registry, but the data/email itself isn't stored there. The only way that user will have the "sensitive" information on another machine is if they started Outlook on that computer.

If you are super paranoid, you could also disable cached mode for that user through policies as well so the ost file is never created on that users computers. Can also disable their ability to create PST files too if you want to take it further.

Comment: I had hoped that that it might be possible to exclude the whole Outlook profile using "Exclude directories in roaming profiles" but I don't know which folder contains the Outlook profile information. That is really my question. I'd like to avoid scripting edits to the registry if possible.

Comment: Almost all of it is stored in the .\Appdata\Local directories. Other locations are listed here: https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Where-does-Microsoft-Outlook-2010-save-my-information-and-configurations-e178f6d6-1515-4c7e-8202-6c7f4794c0a3